# Drupal as a 3-tier system model

Tags: 7

We are planning to create an 'agency' site on drupal. The 'agency' site will serve as 3-tiered system model composed of the following levels:
1. Agents (users)
2. Agency (agent users will belong to a specific agency)
3. Super Administrator (controls everything, permissions etc)

The idea behind the site is to have the ability to register an 'agency' (only by the super admin), that will in-turn have the ability to create their own users (Agents).

If Agency1 logs in, he should be able to register their own sets of users. So goes with other agencies. New users created should belong exclusively to their respective agencies, automatically upon registration.

Are there any modules out there that can be configured to do this? I have 'Profile 2' Module but I don't think this fits the bill. I am looking at the Groups Module but not sure if this is really the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Organic groups](http://drupal.org/project/og).

In that case, every agency would be a group with a group administrator that could set the users that are part of that agency. Every agency could have its own content, which would be created from the users that are associated with the agency. A user of another agency would not be able to create content for another agency, if not in the case the user is member of both the agencies.

Answer (score 1):

[Organic groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) is the only way to go.

Besides that, you should disable the option for the users to registers themselves (in User Management / User settings / **Only site administrators can create new user accounts**).
You can then create users with administrator privileges to create users (agency managers) and agencies.

With organic groups you can also customize if a user can / cannot see the content from another agency. Here are more modules which work with OG: [link](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid:90%20bs_project_sandbox:0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc).

A Drupal distribution built on top of Drupal and OG is Drupal Commons: [here's a live site with that functionallity](http://commons.acquia.com/) (also in this case, you should disable user registration and group creation by normal users).

Install the OG module with others modules or the DC distribution and give it a test. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks! I was playing around og. There seems to be a pending issue for og for when adding a new user to a group here: http://drupal.org/node/911256 which is still unresolved since december of last year. I have yet to try it out with drupal 6 but I trust that it would become a cumbersome installations of too many modules for my needs - a real estate (agency-based) website... any thoughts?

Comment: I am still building with D6! You should also stick with D6 if you want to customize things more... a lot of little modules for organic groups are not available for D7

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! I am now doing away with og. and simply use the built in user module and modify it to include 'grouping' fields and fortunately i am now about to finish this project just by using these modules in drupal 7: (core) user, node reference, and views. The views is the beast!